# How responsive are current transducers?

Tags: current-measurement, transducer

We are using an ([XD-V5-01](http://www.ndmeter.co.uk/files/ND_XD_Transducer_Brochure1.pdf)) to measure an AC current but what we are not sure of is how responsive devices like this are.

Do they accurately reflect the current being measured instantly (100-200 ms)? The spec sheet states 'Less than 1 second', but is this similar for all current transducers?

Comment: There are many different current transducers available.  Most should have specified bandwidth, which should give a clue on what phase lag one can expect at the frequency of interest.  For example, closed-loop LEM current transducers have -3 dB bandwidth around 100 kHz.

Comment: Additionally, the part you mention does not seem to be an instantaneous CT.  Rather it gives the mean or rms value, which cannot be calculated instantaneously.  This is the reason for the slow output (< 1 second).  Most other CT used for current control output the instantaneous current amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really easy to say, because the device you are linking to is an integrated product, not the raw current transducer. In other words, besides the current-sensing component, there is likely a microcontroller or RMS-to-DC converter in the device. This device integrates the current signal over some amount of time and then outputs a 4-20mA or 0-5VDC signal proportional to the RMS current that has flown through the transducer.

To make this answer a bit more general: whether they are using a hall-effect sensor or a current transformer internally, the bare sensor has an instantaneous response (sub-microsecond even with a compensated current transformer topology). However, such a signal is not compatible with 4-20mA or 0-5V because the current signal is AC. Therefore, the manufacturer has built something that integrates the current signal over at least one entire current cycle (20ms for 50Hz), but judging from the marketing material likely more cycles. This is the main source of the lag from input to output.

Answer (score 0):

It would be unlikely that you could expect the response time of all current transducers to be the same. Different manufacturers and even within different models from the same manufacturer it is for sure that varying techniques are used that will change the device response time. Even the type of device output interface (4-20mA) or (0-5V) could have a bearing on the device response time.

So if response time is important to your application you should work closely with your supplier to understand exactly what factors are at play. You also have the option to characterize the particular device you have selected through lab testing of a set of sample units.